# Downshift remaining IDs after function remove()

Tags: javascript

I'm using Javascript and I'm having problems trying to remove several  elements.
Each div has a specific ID, like this:

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
<div id='4'></div>
```

Each div has a button that fires the remove() function

```
document.getElementById(count).remove()
```

Count is a variable that is increased whenever I create a new div

The remove() function works, but it creates a gap. IF i remove the div with id=2, then:

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
<div id='4'></div>
```

But I would like that the remaining IDs could downshift like this:

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
```

I guess I need a for loop but I can't understand how to make it

Comment: Why use ids? What is the purpose of the ids? So that you would need to select the next number and change the id and repeat.

Comment: i can't see any other way that iterating trough the whole items list and update the id's accordingly, on every change

Comment: You would just need to add to your button event so that it updates all the id values of your divs to the correct value.

Comment: @Sirius094 consider using https://api.jquery.com/each/, makes life easier

Comment: @RyanWilson yep sorry, noticed after posting

Comment: @BenYitzhaki No worries.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class on each element, like this:

```html
<div class="a" id='1'></div>
<div class="a" id='2'></div>
<div class="a" id='3'></div>
<div class="a" id='4'></div>
```

And call the following function after each removal:

```js
function resetId(){
    const list = document.getElementsByClassName("a")
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        list[i].id = i + 1
    }
}
```

However, it might be better to just not use IDs in this case. By applying the same class to all your elements, there's no need to readjust the numbering, and you can select (or remove) the `n`<sup>th</sup> element using:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("a")[n]
```

Comment: So I need a separate function to reset the IDs? I thought I could reset the IDs in the same function where I remove a div

Comment: @Sirius094 No, you can move this code where `document.getElementById(count).remove()` is called

Comment: just wanted to say @FZs its `i++` not `i+1` :) good answer tho

Answer (score 1):

**This would probably be best achieved using jquery.**

Here is the working code below:

```js
$("div").each(function(i) {    
  $(this).attr('id', ++i);
});

$("#remove").click(function() {
  $("#2").remove();
  $("div").each(function(i) {    
  $(this).attr('id', ++i);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=""><span>0</span></div>
<div id=""><span>0</span></div>
<div id=""><span>0</span></div>
<div id=""><span>0</span></div>
<div id=""><span>0</span></div>

<a href="#" id="remove">remove</a>
```

> How it works

First `$(this).attr('id', ++i);` this line here is used to add a number to div id. Ive repeated it in the remove function [`("#remove").click(function()`] This is because once a div has been removed the will be a number change.

This in affect is a loop. Without all the lines of code. Which is why i like jquery :)

The div id name is found here after they have been written `$("#2").remove();` `#2` refers to the `<div id="2">` As you would in css.

If you notice, with an inspection the numbers down shift as 1 is removes as per your request.

In order to use jquery you have to link the library. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

> A Pure Javascript Version

```js
function resetId(){
    var div=document.getElementsByClassName("div")
    for(i in div){
        div[i].id=i++
    }
}

function clicked() {
 var elem = document.getElementById("1");
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  resetId();
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="0">div</div>
<div class="div" id="1">div</div>
<div class="div" id="2">div</div>
<div class="div" id="3">div</div>

<a href="#" onclick="clicked()">Remove</a>
```

> How it Works

This section here is your loop:

```
for(i in div){
    div[i].id=i++
}
```

This section quite simply rewrites the numbers 0 - 4 after one has been removed.
The reason it starts from 0, is because in programming we start counting from 0. Hay 0 is a number too guys :).

The `i++` Is a basically a mini int [ish] that is increased as the loop counts through how many divs there are.

This `var elem = document.getElementById("1");` & this `elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);` Is why I find jquery more acceptable in this situation. Its a bit less faf.

Finally `resetId();` We have to call the function otherwise it doesn't that anything has changed, because computers are silly and need to be told.

**Furter Reading**

https://api.jquery.com/

http://www.lucemorker.com/blog/javascript-vs-jquery-quick-overview-and-comparison

Comment: Thank your for you in-depth answer :) I'll definitely take a look at these links

Comment: @Sirius094 I like in-depth awnsers. Hate here's code. Now work it out for your self. If it fixed your issue and the code does what you want it too please dont forget to tick it off :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using classes and referencing elements by index instead. IDs should remain persistent for clarity.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('my-class')[2].remove();
```

```html
<div class="my-class" id="thing1">One</div>
<div class="my-class" id="thing2">Two</div>
<div class="my-class" id="thing3">Three</div>
<div class="my-class" id="thing4">Four</div>
```